# How to select only those users that have multiple records attached to them?

Tags: sql

I have the following query. I'd like to adjust to select only those user_ids that have multiple subscription_plans. As an example if a user_id 4 has just one subscription_plan_id of, he shouldn't show up.

If user_id 5 has subscription_plan_id of 2 and 3, he should show up. Any advice on how to do this?

```
select user_id, subscription_plan_id, created_at from
subscriptions where 
(subscription_plan_id = 47 or 
subscription_plan_id = 78)
and created_at between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into these SQL keywords:

- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- COUNT(DISTINCT [column])

Okay, fine, I'll do it for you.... [grumble]....

```
SELECT
  user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT subscription_plan_id), MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at)
FROM
  subscriptions
WHERE 
  created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY
  user_id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT subscription_plan_id) > 1
;
```

Comment: "Grumble" :). This works but only returns the user_id with the first subscription. How do I get all the subscription_plan_ids for that user?

Comment: I meant this returns the number of subscriptions. I'm trying to get the actual subscription_plan_ids though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to filter out the users that have some number of subscriptions, in your case less than 1.
Try something like this

```
select user_id, subscription_plan_id, created_at 
from subscriptions 
where (subscription_plan_id = 47 or 
   subscription_plan_id = 78)
   and created_at between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'
   AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM subscriptions ss 
                   GROUP BY ss.user_id 
                   HAVING COUNT(subscription_plan_id) > 1)  ;
```